# How to select only the country code without a flag in React Native

Tags: react-native

I need to select only the country code without a flag.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg7aa.jpg)

This is my input box. I need to add a country code and phone number separately.

```
    <PhoneInput
        containerStyle={{ marginRight: 5}}
        ref={phoneInputRef}
        placeholder="Enter phone number"
        defaultValue={phone}
        multiline={false}
        disabled={!editable}
        layout="first"
        onChangeText={(newValue) => {
            setPhoneNumberError('');
            setPhone(newValue);
        }}
        withDarkTheme
        withShadow
        autoFocus
    />
</View>
```

I tried it in this way. But it shows a flag with a country code and also I am not able to resize. I removed *onchangetext* and *value*, but the width can't be changed.

Comment: Please mention which library you are using for country code picking ?

Comment: You must mention library you are using and show the code clearly! Thats better!

Comment: import PhoneInput from 'react-native-phone-number-input';

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69264903/edit) (change) your question to include the information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the *country flag*, change the value of `layout` from `"first"` to `"second"`.

It will look like this:

```
layout="second"
```

[image]

Comment: i need to reduce height of input box so i user  height: getPercentageHeight(50) but i can see country code and not able to see phone input area(it like hiding). i need to reduce height of phoneinput.

Comment: Try changing height of inputContainer using textInputStyle={{height: 50}} . Also refer to the mentioned props by this package https://github.com/garganurag893/react-native-phone-number-input#props

Accept my answer if it helped you to hide the country flag. You can ask a new question if you want more help.